# Error: Mysql ~ Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql

My Mysql Table:

```
ID: Int : AUTO_INCREMENT
Game: Text : No null : No Default
Password: Text : No null : No Default
Description: Text : No null : No Default
Difficulty: TinyText : No null: No Default
Realm: Int : No null: No Default
Empty: Int : Default 0
timestamp: Int : No null : No Default
```

sql query:

```
INSERT INTO games (Game, Password, Description, Difficulty, Realm,
timestamp) VALUES ('$game', '$pass', '$desc', '$diff', '$charName', '$Realm', '$timestamp')
```

And I am getting

> "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

and I don't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you noticed your `INSERT` statement as shown below. You are mentioning 6 columns and passing 7 values. That's why the error.

```
INSERT INTO games (Game, Password, Description, Difficulty, Realm, timestamp) <- 6 fields
VALUES ('$game', '$pass', '$desc', '$diff', '$charName', '$Realm', '$timestamp') <- 7 values
```

Also, your columns names (`Password` and `timestamp`) are key words and so try escaping them using backtique.

Answer (score 0):

In your insertion query, you have 6 columns. However, you have 7 values for the 6 columns.

As a result, "column count doesn't match".

Hope it helps.